# How to map special characters in CSV to something else when processing via datatool

Tags: datatool, active-characters

The [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) mentions that certain special characters are automatically mapped to the typesetting equivalent when loading a database in *raw* mode (via `\DTLloadrawdb`). If you want to change the mapping, use (for example)

```
\DTLrawmap{£}{\pounds}
```

However, how do I map *active* characters like `%`, `$`, `&`, `_`, ... to something else? The following minimal example fails to map `%` to something other than `\%` (for obvious reasons; `%` is an active comment character):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,datatool}
\begin{filecontents*}{scores.csv}
Name, Score
Alpha, 80.2%
Beta, 91.3%
Average, 85.75%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLrawmap{%}{\$}% <--- this fails...
\DTLloadrawdb{scores}{scores.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{scores}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *escaped* version of the character in the `<string>` part of `\DTLrawmap{<string>}{<replacement>}`. For example,

```
\DTLrawmap{\%}{\$}
```

would replace `%` in the source CSV with `\$`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,datatool}
\begin{filecontents*}{scores.csv}
Name, Score
Alpha, 80.2%
Beta, 91.3%
Average, 85.75%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb{scoresA}{scores.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{scoresA}

\DTLrawmap{\%}{\$}% Map % to \$
\DTLloadrawdb{scoresB}{scores.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{scoresB}

\end{document}
```

From the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf):

> Naturally, the mappings must be set *prior* to loading the data with `\DTLloadrawdb`.